# Objective c - Some array items are not shown in my UITableView (some shown twice)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have my main view controller that shows a `UITableView`.
Each cell of this are custom (I've created a `UIView` for custom presentation).

For showing these items in my tableView, I populate an array with the content of the "allFilesFolderPath" folder with this code:

```
- (void)configureView {
    _itemArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:allFilesFolderPath error:nil];
}
```

and

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.itemArray count];
}
```

and I create my custom cells for showing them with :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    myItem = [self.itemArray objectAtIndex:row];
    NSLog(@"My Item : %@", _itemArray.description);

    static NSString *CellIdentifer = @"cardCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifer];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifer];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

When I print the array with the `NSLog`, I get the correct list of item and in the alphabetical order (like how they are stored in the Documents location on my iPhone):

```
My Item : (
Music,
Music10,
Music2,
Music3,
Music4,
Music5,
Music6,
Music7,
Music8,
Music9,
Photos,
Videos
)
```

But when I run the app in my iPhone (or in the simulator), the cells are correctly displayed (in the order) until the eighth item. After this number, in my case, instead of having "Music8", "Music9", "Photos", "Video" I come back to the beginning of th array so "Music", "Music10", "Music2" and "Music3"

To better understand what I get, here is the screenshots :

[image]

[image]

I'm really lost! I've searched (and search again) what I'm doing wrong but I don't find anything, everything is correct for me.

Please help me to find my issue so that I can sleep normally.

EDIT: here is the method I've set to retrieve the myItem string from my other class :

```
+ (NSString *)getItemName {

    return myItem;

}
```

And here is how I retrieve it from my other class :

```
NSString *test = [ViewController getItemName];    
_itemName.text = test;
```

EDIT2 : Here is the code used for setting my custom TableViewCell
(sorry for missing these informations

```
    #import "TableViewCell.h"

@implementation TableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code

    [self cardSetup];

}



- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}



- (void)cardSetup {

    _cardView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    _cardView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    _cardView.layer.shadowRadius = 1;
    _cardView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3;


    NSString *test = [ViewController getItemName];    
    _itemName.text = test;

}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is this call named "dequeueReusableCell...". Table view cells are *reused*. If 8 cells fit on the screen, and you scroll the view up, your ninth row will reuse the cell that was used for the first row. That's why you have to set up your cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath, which apparently you refuse to do.

Cells are used just for display. They are not used for storing data. You should have a data model, accessed by everyone. cellForRowAtIndexPath *reads* from that data model. And then if something happens (for example by tapping on a button in a cell) that changes the data model, then you change the data model, and the data model should tell all the interested parties that the model has changed.

Your cell in one view and a UILabel elsewhere should definitely not be connected at all. Any changes should propagate through your data model.

Comment: I've didn't thought of using a class to store data, and I don't think why as it is a clean model !
I will try this tomorrow as it's late where I live, and let you know. Thanks !

Comment: So I've created my data model with the help of ray wenderlich tuto (https://www.raywenderlich.com/1797/ios-tutorial-how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-part-1). I've set a Doc and a Data class that contain my title.
I've successfully created my TableViewCellDoc item, but when I send it in cellForRowAtIndexPath to my cell object, I get nothing inside the label. See the code I use for sending it: TableViewCellDoc *item = [self.itemArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    TableViewCell *cellItem = [[TableViewCell alloc] init];
    cellItem.itemName.text = item.data.title;

Comment: Hum I've found the issue, it came from the initialization of my cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath. I used to do it like UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cardCell"]; instead of TableViewCell (my custom class so) **cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cardCell"];. I can now print all the item through the delegate method, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You're not using `myItem` anywhere in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`  Your cells seem to be getting their text from some other method, when they should be getting it from `celForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: Please see my edited question, I've added the method I use to retrieve myItem string from my other class

Comment: @Synny, you mention an `awakeFromNib` method which you still haven't posted.

Comment: @Synny, your `+ (NSString *)getItemName` method is a class method, so the `myItem` inside it is only a single instance and is probably being accessed by many different cells.  Instead, use `[self.itemArray objectAtIndex:row]` inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to set the text.  And if you need to, forward it to other instance methods.  But you shouldn't use class methods for something like this.

Comment: @Gavin again I've edited my question for posting the code
Hash88 Ok, I will try this way in the next few minutes